# Optimising boost::python::object instances

Tags: c++, python, numpy, boost-python, python-c-extension

I recently started using [Boost's Python](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/python/doc/index.html) library to wrap parts of a rather large C++ library.

Quite by chance, I discovered that every Python object created by Boost Python, is at least bigger than the size of a Python List.

### Simple types

Using the [`noddy_NoddyType` example](http://docs.python.org/2/extending/newtypes.html#the-basics) from the [C-Python API docs](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/index.html), I can quite easily expose a new object type instance, `noddy_NoddyObject`.

Using the raw C-Python API, this is as small and simple as a custom Python object can be:-

```
>>> import noddy, sys

>>> print sys.getsizeof( noddy.Noddy )   # PyTypeObject size?
872
>>> print sys.getsizeof( noddy.Noddy() ) # PyObject size
16
```

And to compare with a base object:-

```
>>> print sys.getsizeof( object )
872
>>> print sys.getsizeof( object() )
16
```

That's as expected, but what about when I expose `noddy_NoddyObject` using Boost Python?

```
>>> print sys.getsizeof( noddy.Noddy )
904
>>> print sys.getsizeof( noddy.Noddy() )
80
```

Say what?!! That's not ideal... Object instances are 5 times bigger than they need to be!

(This will differ on non-64-bit machines.)

On the Boost Python wiki, there's [some explanation](http://wiki.python.org/moin/boost.python/InternalDataStructures) for the extra bloat:-

> **Memory consumption**
>
> In general, a wrapped C++ object with a corresponding Python object is
>   the size of:
>
> - a new-style class (derived from 'object' in Python)
>     instance plus
> - **the extra size required to allow variable-length data
>     in the instance**, plus
> - the size of the C++ object, plus
> - <strike>the size of a vtable pointer</strike>, plus  a pointer to the C++ object's
>     instanceholder, plus
> - zero or more bytes of padding required to ensure
>     that the instanceholder is properly aligned.
>
> You can see this in `boost/python/object/instance.hpp`. Most Python objects are represented by `instance<value_holder<T> >`, for some C++ class `T`.

But there is notably no indication as to how to reduce instance size, nor how to use a custom `PyTypeObject`.

### Sequence Types

So, in [`instance.hpp`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/boost/python/object/instance.hpp), you can see that all `boost::python::instance`'s use `PyObject_VAR_HEAD` in their base class's declaration. This would explain the much closer similarity in size of a Boost Python-compiled `noddy_NoddyObject`, to that of a Python `list`, or `numpy.array`:-

```
>>> print sys.getsizeof( list )
872
>>> print sys.getsizeof( list() )
72
>>> print sys.getsizeof( numpy.array )
72
>>> print sys.getsizeof( numpy.array() )
80
```

(Oh, that's interesting.. If I'm not mistaken, `numpy.array` is the size of a minimal `PyObject` instance, which is much smaller than a `PyTypeObject`. I wonder what the implications are there..)

### Memory management

Besides object size, the concern that led me here was one of heap transactions. I have a C++ base class, which is comprised almost solely of memory management-related features: it has `new` and `delete` operators; plenty of reference counting-related methods, and is inherited by about a hundred other C++ classes.

Having once read the [C-Python API docs on Defining new Types](http://docs.python.org/2/extending/newtypes.html#the-basics), I thought a new type would be appropriate here. By defining a new `PyTypeObject` struct, and pointing its members (`tp_alloc`, etc.) to the C++ class's operators and member functions, I thought I could get the Python interpreter to call the C++ member functions directly. Derived class types would then have no functionality duplicated between a typical `boost::python::object` instance and the (already managed) C++ classes.

Using `bp::class_<>` templates, I figured both C++ code and Python code would separately be managing memory to class instances, which seems potentially very inefficient.

### Making a new `PyTypeObject`

By using a new `PyTypeObject`, I think all my concerns would be resolved. The memory footprint of simple objects could be much smaller (I'd be very pleased if I could get `noddy_NoddyObject` down to 24 bytes) and it seems there would be far more flexibility with how that memory is managed.

So, has anyone else ever felt the need to define a new `PyTypeObject`, different to Boost Python instances' default? How would one go about this?

By going for the larger base type, it seems like Boost is losing both efficiency and flexibility.  It's always more painful to lose weight than it is to gain more.

Comment: Are these numbers from a debug or release build?

Comment: I didn't specify any compile options... But good point. I'll update the compile options to use those of the Python build, which is a release build (2.7.4-1 x86_64 from Arch Linux extra repo). I'll update the post if any changes..

Comment: Just made `distutils` compile the extension, and there's no difference in object or instance size. It builds with "-O2" optimisation, generic tuning and some other options, but no aggressive optimisations like inter-procedural optimisation, nor debugging symbols, in the extension or the system library.

Comment: Is there a specific problem trying to be solved?  Although interesting, as it stands now, I am not quite sure the question is a good fit for the Stack Overflow Q&A format.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Yes, there was a specific problem, which I've now expanded upon and attempted to clarify. I hope that's better...

Comment: @sau if you make an edit please fix *all* the issues in the post whilst you're at it.